# In Indonesia, can a clerk of courts be made to issue a court's decision without a bribe?

Tags: court, indonesia

A friend of mine sue someone else for divorce. The wife appeals. It took 8 months from the time the decisions is made until the country court raise the documents to the high court.

The high court doesn't upheld the country's court decisions quickly. My friend got the message on January 2016.

Now, it's March 2016. The decision is already there. All the court clerk need to do is to tell the decision to the opponent. Then the opponent will have sometime to appeal again.

The wife is a little crazy. She would appeal just to postpone the divorce to hurt her husband due to her religious beliefs. She has no money, does not understand the law, and cannot do anything to challenge the court's decisions.

Here is the catch. The court clerk simply didn't do his job.

We consult lawyers and the lawyer told us that court clerks have unlimited amount of time to notify the wife.

That's it. The court clerks can postpone doing his job indefinitely. If we want this to happen faster, we got to bribe court clerks.

I already knows that justice in Indonesia sucks. I have no idea that the laws is this depraved.

It seems that the case has been common. Many court decisions could take decades. Someone who occupy another house illegally can keep postponing any court decisions without any merit, for example.

So how should I speed the court clerks' job within reasonable amount of time without having to bribe him? Bribing is also punished severely but done so commonly lawyers consider that part of the game.

Comment: Can you hire a third party to serve process in Indonesia?

Comment: Perhaps just pay the bribe. That's a pragmatic suggestion. Sometimes you just can't win.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can report that said clerk to the Monitoring Information System called SIWASMARI. Please don't bribe them as you will not change our criminal justice system.

You can also send some mail to the Monitoring Court Body located in

> Kepala Badan Pengawasan MA RI Jl. Jend. Ahmad Yani Kav. 58 By Pass Cempaka Putih Timur Jakarta Pusat – 13011

You have to be active and keep contacting the clerk. Tell them that you will report them to the Monitoring Court Body.

Comment: My friend hired a lawyer. $50 and he got what he wants.

Comment: Basically the court clerk has an excuse. The wife have moved. However, that is irrelevant. The court clerk should just send the notification to the address on file and that's it.

Comment: And the lawyer makes him do exactly that. The wife doesn't get the letter and we save supreme court appeal. The wife simply doesn't want to get a divorce due to irrational (religious) reasons. All she did is making divorce more expensive.